# How to use xargs to delete redis keys containing `\\`?

Tags: xargs

Goal: I want to delete redis keys matching a pattern and for this I use `xargs`

If I use this command
`redis-cli KEYS "*SomeService::getFromId*"`

I see a lot of results, example

```
redis-cli KEYS "*SomeService::getFromId*
1) "sa.:App\\Services\\SomeService::getFromId.deb525724eacbadb4ccdda90d787a41e"
2) "sa.:App\\Services\\SomeService::getFromId.0e8333deeded62761735adab2a6516f5"
```

Then when I run:
`redis-cli KEYS "*SomeService::getFromId*" | xargs -n 1 redis-cli del`

I get

```
(integer) 0
(integer) 0
```

So nothing is deleted.

If I try to debug by running xargs with echo I get this result:

```
redis-cli KEYS "*SomeService::getFromId*" | xargs -n 1 echo
sa.:AppServicesSomeService::getFromId.5683abfb173fe66bc078df0a6a85eeb7
sa.:AppServicesSomeService::getFromId.4df008768a8e05b6dd7bdab51b00a774
```

I notice that the `\\` is changed and removed by xargs -n 1.

How to keep the correct key so that means
`sa.:App\\Services\\SomeService::getFromId.deb525724eacbadb4ccdda90d787a41e`
instead of removing `\\` and having
`sa.:AppServicesSomeService::getFromId.5683abfb173fe66bc078df0a6a85eeb7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just skipped using xargs and used instead after running `redis-cli` the following

```
EVAL "return redis.call('del', unpack(redis.call('keys', '*SomeService::getFromId*')))" 0
```

And worked great
got output
`(integer) 96`

and all 96 keys of that pattern were gone.